# Linha horizontal no meio de uma lista não ordenada HTML

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma lista não ordenada que possui alguns itens de lista e gostaria de colocar uma linha horizontal (horizontal rule < hr >) nela, bem no meio, com altura de 2px. Eu tentei botar `vertical-align: middle` mas a linha ficou em cima dos itens de lista. Eu gostaria de botar ela atrás deles, deve ter alguma propriedade do css que permita isso.

Os itens de lista podem aparecer ou não, dependendo de outros fatores. Ou seja, havendo ou não itens de lista, a linha horizontal deve sempre estar no meio da div.

Alguma dica?

Segue o código que tenho.

```
<ul>
    <hr style="height:2px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <? if($primeiro_ponto != NULL && $ultimo_ponto != NULL && $quantidade_de_trajetos>0){foreach($conteudos as $ils){ echo $ils; }}?>       
</ul>
```

Comment: Evite fazer títulos grandes...

Comment: faço esse tipo de coisa com muita frequÊncia em menus...é mais simples do que parece, vou lhe fornecer um exemplo bem prático.

Answer (score 6):

## `<hr>` filho de `<ul>`

O Chrome mostra corretamente uma linha entre os itens da lista. Usei o seguinte código para teste:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <hr style="height:2px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"/>
     <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

O resultado obtido foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## `<hr>` dentro de um `<li>`

Outra alternativo é colocar a linha dentro de um item e remover a formatação do item. Exemplo:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;"><hr style="height:2px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"/></li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

## Borda em um `<li>`

Uma terceira abordagem é colocar uma borda superior ou inferior nos itens da lista. Exemplo:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
     <li style="border-top: 2px #000 solid; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

---

#### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/NTrgD/)

Observação: evite usar CSS *inline*, isto é, misturado com HTML. Dê preferência para usar um arquivo CSS separado.

Answer (score 2):

faça uma li com uma classe "separador" veja no exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/A4Lj7/1

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>maçã</li>
    <li class="separador"></li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li class="separador"></li>
    <li>laranja</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li.separador {
    width: 90%; /* coloque aqui a largura da linha */
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<hr>`

no css3 apenas coloque essa tag e ele fara uma linha na horizontal